# Separate a .txt file into separate strings

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring, ios5, xcode4.2

I already know how to upload a file and place its contents into a string with:

```
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WellBalanced Recipes" ofType:@"txt"] 
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                      error:NULL];
```

However, I would like to parse this text document into separate strings.  For example, if I had different recipes in the same document, I would like to somehow separate each recipe.

Comment: is there any pattern that allows you to separate one recipe from another one?  If so, you could then use NSString's `componentsSeparatedByString` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator`

```
NSArray *data = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: If I answered your question please click the grey cheek mark to show this question is answered.